# confused about the output of the following Python code:

Tags: python

```py
value = 6
class A:
    value = 5

a = A()
a.value = 10
print(value)
```

I tried running this python program and was expecting an output of 10. However, the actual output is 6. I am relatively new to python and don't know why hte output is 6 instead of 10.

Comment: Because you printed `value`, not `a.value`.

Comment: Why would you expect `10` as an output? The class `A` does not affect your code. If you keep only the first and last line, it will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation in the code

```
# this is a global variable, it exists outside the class.
# if this value represents an attribute of the class A
# then it shouldn't be here, since it breaks encapsulation.
value = 6 

class A: 
    # this is an attribute of the class
    # note that like this is a static attribute
    # (because it's defined outside the constructor)
    value = 5

    # this is the constructor of your class.
    # unless you are going to use static classes, better put attributes here, prefixed with self.
    def __init__(self):
        # this is an attribute declared in the constructor
        # it's not static and it's accessed only via an instance of a class

        self.anotherValue = 3

# here you instantiate the class A (consider using better names)
a = A()  

# here you can access the static attribute of A (notice the capital A)
print(A.value)   # gives 5 

# you can change the attribute value of an instance of A (notice the underscore a, since we are using an instance of A here)

a.value = 10
print(a.value)    # gives 10

# if you are not going to use attributes as static, better use attributes declared in the constructor.

a.anotherValue = 10
print(a.anotherValue)    # gives 10

# here you are just printing the global variable, which has a value of 6
print(value)
```

Things can be a bit confusing at the beginning, that's why it's very important to give proper names.

Instead of a class named `A`, an instance named `a` and an attribute named `value`, I'd suggest you practice with real names.

You can have a class `Animal` which has an instance `dog` and an instance `spider`.

This instances have attributes, like `number_of_legs` which might have different values for each instance (4 for cats, 8 for spiders)

You can have static attributes for animals, which do not depend on instances, like `isAlive` (all Animals are alive, well not always, but let's assume we only consider alive animals)